# How to set the tint color with PINRemoteImage?

Tags: uiimageview, uicolor

I tried following to set the tint color of the image after the image is downloaded using the PINRemoteImage, but it doesn't work. How can I set the tint color of the image with PINRemoteImage?

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.pin_setImage(from: URL(string: "https://pinterest.com/kitten.jpg")!)
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, had to set the image rendering model after the image is downloaded, by passing in the `PINRemoteImageManagerImageCompletion` callback in this method `imageView.pin_setImage(from: URL?, completion: PINRemoteImageManagerImageCompletion?)`

```
imageView.pin_setImage(from: "https://pinterest.com/kitten.jpg") { result in
    result.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = result.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
}
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```